# "Did you contacted them" or "did you contact them"

Tags: grammaticality, questions, verb-agreement, simple-past

> - Did you **contacted** them?
> - Did you **contact** them?

Which of above sentences is correct? If both are correct, what's the difference between them? 
In which scenarios can I use them?

Comment: Omigoshtaba - you need to attend basic elementary English classes and not ask this  question here.

Comment: "Did you contact them?" is the correct answer because it is grammatical. Blessed Geek has given you good advice, ELU is not a site designed to help beginners of English.

Comment: More to the point, this is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate. (I am not exaggerating. This question gets asked once a week, every week.) And there's no point in migrating it to ELL, either, as it will be a duplicate of a duplicate there as well. So the real issue here is not whether you picked the most appropriate site, but whether you searched it before asking. Please make sure to always do just that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auxiliary verb *do*, in all its parts (*did*, *does*, *don't*, *didn't*, *doesn't*) is **always** followed by the infinitive ("eat", "be", "contact") **never** by the past ("ate", "was", "contacted") or the past participle ("eaten", "been", "contacted").

Comment: Actually, of course, it is rarely followed by any form of _be_, but the point still stands.